# Managing lots of Websphere Liberty (websphere-liberty) app servers

Tags: websphere-liberty

I wonder if there is a way to manage multiple was liberty profile app servers in one place? Like WAS full profile has a WAS console where you can start , stop, configure, generate-pluging etc. features  but something similar ?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Admin Center](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-mp&topic=twlp_ui) feature, available since version 8.5.5.2.

Comment: Please strongly consider putting the key content of the answer  here, link only answers are strongly discouraged, as when the link breaks all information is lost.